# How can I check if UDP server is alive in Java?

Tags: java, udp

There is a remote UDP server with port 23040.
I'd like to a monitor program to check if UDP server is alive.
Below is my code:

```
private boolean checkUdpConnection()
{
    boolean result = false;
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.150.154", 23040);
        socket.getOutputStream();
        socket.close();
        result = true;
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I run this code, I got "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect".
If I changed to port 9999 when new Socket(), which 9999 is not opened in server side, I still got same ConnectException.

Can you kindly tell me why I can't connect to opened port 23040?
Thank you.

Comment: I started the same UDP server on my notebook, which will listen on localhost UDP 23040, I have changed to new Socket("localhost", 23040), but got same ConnectException.

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868350/in-java-how-to-achieve-udp-port-scanning